# Create constant from NSString *const type

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, constants

I am managing some of the global constants in `CamSettingsConstants.h/m` objective-c files. In `.h`:

`extern NSString *const CAMERA_CAPTURE_SESSION_PRESET;`

In `.m`:

`NSString *const CAMERA_CAPTURE_SESSION_PRESET = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;`

Unfortunately, this results in a compile time error:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

I'm not sure why this is the case as this is declared as:

`AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);` in `AVCaptureSession.h`. Is there anyway, this is possible?

Comment: When already a const string is defined why you want to create a local version of that constant? Instead you can directly use AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480??

Comment: I want to collect my constants in a single place so I can tinker with them later.

Comment: Is it an issue if you simply lose the "const" keyword? Since CAMERA_CAPTURE_SESSION_PRESET is extern the linker is responsible for setting this parameter, not the compiler. So I think this is not really possible. Also you could use #define.